# Hiding a label in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I hide a label in JavaScript for the following for `id="email"` if my html is as follows

```
<label>Email : <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="doe@gmail.com" /></label>
```

Comment: You can't hide the label without hiding the input ?

Comment: I already hide its input only label left

Comment: It sounded a bit like that was what you wanted, if you want to hide both Oriols answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the label is the parent of the input, you can get the input by its id, get its parent, and style it with `display: none` (or alternatively, `visibility: hidden`).

```css
document.getElementById('email').parentElement.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add a CSS class to the label with jQuery. The class just needs to contain:

```
display: none;
```

And triggers on some jQuery event if that's what you want.

You may find the following helpful:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/